# PHP Regex Match URL but don't match Image

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use preg_match_all to extract all urls from a block of HTML code. I'm also trying to ignore all images.

Example HTML block:

```
$html = '<p>This is a test</p><br>http://www.facebook.com<br><img src="http://www.google.com/photo.jpg">www.yahoo.com https://www.aol.com<br>';
```

I'm using the following to try and build an array of URLS only. (not images)

```
if(preg_match_all('~(?:(?:https://)|(?:http://)|(?:www\.))(?![^" ]*(?:jpg|png|gif|"))[^" <>]+~', $html, $links))
{ 
 print_r($links); 
}
```

In the example above the $links array should contain:

```
http://www.facebook.com, www.yahoo.com, https://www.aol.com
```

Google is left out because it contains the .jpg image extension. The problem occurs when I add an image like this one to $html:

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/image%201.jpg">
```

It seems as though the percent sign causes preg_match to break apart the URL and extract the following "link".

```
http://www.google.com/image
```

Any idea how to grab ONLY url's that are not images? (even if they contain special characters that urls could commonly have)

Comment: stop using regular expressions.

Comment: This question was asked earlier today. `%20` is the URL encoding for a space. Likely your regex is matching against a _space_, not a literal "%20". And it's stopping at the space because that's what that regex says: `[^" <>]+`.

Comment: "stop using regular expressions" - do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Nope, not matching against against a space. It is as shown in the example above. Please see $html

Comment: sorry. interrupted while answering, .. start using DOM

Comment: How do you match urls (not a href's) using dom?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly or not, but when I run your pattern against `$html = '<p>This is a test</p><br>http://www.facebook.com<br><img src="http://www.google.com/photo.jpg"><br><img src="http://www.google.com/image%201.jpg"><br>www.yahoo.com https://www.aol.com<br>';`, it seems to pull what you want.  Here is an example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e497a4692467abd43fdf9ba75ea059dddaacc6f5

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM allows you to recognize the structure of an HTML document. In your case to recognize the parts you want to fetch the urls from.

1. Load the HTML using DOM
2. Fetch urls from link href attributes using Xpath (only if you want them, too)
3. Fetch text nodes from the DOM using Xpath
4. Use RegEx on text node value to match urls

Here is an example implementation:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
  <p>This is a test</p>
  <br>
  http://www.facebook.com
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.google.com/photo.jpg">
  www.yahoo.com 
  https://www.aol.com
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
  <!-- http://comment.ingored.url -->
  <br>
HTML;

$urls = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// fetch urls from link href attributes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//a[@href]/@href') as $href) {
  $urls[] = $href->value;
}

// fetch urls inside text nodes
$pattern = '(
 (?:(?:https?://)|(?:www\.))
 (?:[^"\'\\s]+)
)xS';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/html/body//text()') as $text) {
  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all($pattern, $text->nodeValue, $matches);
  foreach ($matches[0] as $href) {
    $urls[] = $href;
  }
}

var_dump($urls);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "http://www.google.com"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "http://www.facebook.com"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "www.yahoo.com"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "https://www.aol.com"
}
```